# Laravel mysql order by with wherehas

Tags: mysql, laravel-9

I have 2 tables :

1. users - `id, name, email, mobile`
2. user_info - `id, user_id, store_name, startup_date`
3. User Model

```
class EloquentUser extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'mobile',
    ];
}
```

2. User Info Model

```
class UserInfo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
    public $table = 'user_info';
    
}
```

Below is relationship on above 2 tables :-

```
public function info() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

I want to order on base of `startup_date` but it is giving error column not found. Below is the query :-

```
$reponse = EloquentUser::with('info')
              ->has('info')
              ->orderBy('info.startup_date')
              ->get();
```

Comment: How would we determine if `startup_date` is mentioned in any model? (or table?)

Comment: It is present in user_info table

Comment: my point was intended to make you think about how can we help if there is almost no visibility into your code etc. All we see is what you place into the question. Also, stating that it exists does not prove that it is properly referenced - can we see your table DDL and the laravel model code please.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: select `users`.*, (select count(*) from `vendor_reviews` where `users`.`id` = `vendor_reviews`.`user_id` and
`vendor_reviews`.`deleted_at` is null) as `reviews_count` from `users` where exists (select * from `roles` inner join `role_users` on `roles`.`id` = `role_users`.`role_id`  where `users`.`id` = role_users`.`user_id` and `roles`.`slug` = 'vendor') and exists (select * from `user_info` where `users`.`id` = `user_info`.`user_id` and `user_info`.`deleted_at` is null
order by `business_name` desc) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null;

Answer (score 0):

You must modify your query and define the inverse relationship in the UserInfo model. The ORM you provided will not give the expected result.
Create inverse relationship

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id','user_id');
}
```

Change the query to

```
UserInfo::with('user')->orderBy('startup_date')->get();
```